# Error when trying to install matplotlib

Tags: macos, matplotlib

When trying to install matploblib using pip or easy_install, I come across the following error:

```
                 numpy: 1.5.1
                        * Could not find the headers for numpy.  You may
                        * need to install the development package.
```

My Mac came with python 2.7 and numpy 1.5.1 installed, so I don't think I messed with those. I found a couple of other threads discussing this problem, but I wasn't able to make those solutions work. Was wondering if anybody else encountered this and figured it out? Thanks!